# How to access variable inside a for-in loop within an async function (javascript/react)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch

So I made this little fetch function in a React project to loop through the returned object and give me a number of something.
 I'm trying to get back the value of **profileCount** to access it outside of the async function. 
How would I do that?

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getProfiles() {
    try {
      const url = '';

      let h = new Headers();
      h.append('Accept', 'application/json');

      let encoded = window.btoa('superuser:superuser');
      let auth = 'Basic ' + encoded;

      h.append('Authorization', auth);

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: h,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
      });
      const data = await response.json();

      let results = data.results;
      let profileCount = 0;

      for (let key in results) {
        let innerObject = results[key];
        for (let newKey in innerObject) {
          if (innerObject[newKey].indexOf('pages/ProfilePage') > -1) {
            profileCount += 1;
            return profileCount;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('test' + err);
    }
  }
  getProfiles();
}, []);
```

Comment: `getProfiles();` Where is the await? Where to you read what is returned? Why are you returning inside of the loop? That return will always exit when you have one.

Comment: create a `profileCount` variable with `useState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good, just relocate the `return` statement after the `for`.

```
      for (let key in results) {
        let innerObject = results[key];
        for (let newKey in innerObject) {
          if (innerObject[newKey].indexOf('pages/ProfilePage') > -1) {
            profileCount += 1;
          }
        }
      }

      return profileCount;
```

The workflow is the following,

```
useEffect(async () => {
  async function getProfiles() {}
  const count = await getProfiles();
}, []);
```

But you might have to do this to avoid warning,

```
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        let response = await fetch('api/data')
      })();
    }, [])
```

Comment: This won't allow the variable to be used outside of the useEffect. How is he going to be able to capture that value? Needs `useState`.

Comment: for that part, you need to await `const a = await getProfiles();`, update the answer.